# Create a column with maximum value (A-Z)

Tags: pandas, alphabetical

I have below dataframe, I want to the create a new column that shows the highest score for the ID. Score is from A-Z. A = low score, Z = high score.

| ID | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | A |
| 001 | B |
| 001 | C |
| 002 | A |
| 002 | A |
| A003 | E |
| A003 | G |
| A003 | G |

Output

| ID | Score | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | A | C |
| 001 | B | C |
| 001 | C | C |
| 002 | A | A |
| 002 | A | A |
| A003 | E | G |
| A003 | G | G |
| A003 | G | G |

Is there any way to accomplish this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `ID` and transform by `max`:

```
df['New Column'] = df.groupby('ID').transform('max')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     ID Score New Column
0   001     A          C
1   001     B          C
2   001     C          C
3   002     A          A
4   002     A          A
5  A003     E          G
6  A003     G          G
7  A003     G          G
```